# Differentiable functions and antiderivative

Tags: real-analysis

I have this function $f(x)$ which is continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb R$. Is the following true - without the assumption that $f$ being absolutely continuous!

$$ \int_{a}^{b} f'(x) dx=f(b)-f(a)$$

Edit: $f$ is infinitely differentiable on $\mathbb R$. I think this may change everything!

Answer (score 2):

No, the derivative need not even be integrable! See Wikipedia's article on [Volterra's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function).

PS: If $f$ is differentiable, then $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Wait: Volterra's function is not *Riemann* integrable. Since the derivative is bounded and Borel, it evidently is Lebesgue integrable. By mentioning absolute continuity, I think this question is about the Lebesgue differentiation theorem which states that the fundamental theorem of calculus holds *precisely* for the absolutely continuous functions.

Answer (score 1):

After edit, it became true, because of continuously $f'(x)$. And now you can use [Newton-Leibniz formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)

Comment: So, the absolute continuity is not necessary.

Comment: @Ashley It is. The formula holds iff $f$ is absolutely continuous.